# WPA_GUI only works as root

Tags: gui, wpa

WPA_gui will only work if I run it as root. I know I need to change its permissions but I cannot figure out where or to what.

I have tried adding the user to the NetDev group but that did not work. Any ideas would be extremely appreciated.

thanks

EDIT:
my /etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
    <policy user="root">
            <allow own="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>

            <allow send_destination="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>
            <allow send_interface="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>

            <allow own="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>

            <allow send_destination="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <allow send_interface="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <allow receive_sender="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1" receive_type="signal"/>
    </policy>
    <policy group="netdev">
            <allow send_destination="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>
            <allow send_interface="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>

            <allow send_destination="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <allow send_interface="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <allow receive_sender="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1" receive_type="signal"/>
    </policy>
    <policy context="default">
            <deny own="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>
            <deny send_destination="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>
            <deny send_interface="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>

            <deny own="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <deny send_destination="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <deny send_interface="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            <deny receive_sender="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1" receive_type="signal"/>
    </policy>
</busconfig>
```

and the read out from command group

```
armtc adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin netdev sambashare
```

It looks that both reference the group netdev but still no joy.

EDIT2: /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant.service & /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant1.service

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant
Exec=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
User=root
SystemdService=wpa_supplicant.service
```

Comment: Have a look here [Use wpa_cli](http://ebixio.com/blog/2011/09/15/how-to-make-wpa_cli-talk-to-wpa_supplicant-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: @ECarterYoung thanks for the advice but it looks like that file is already configured as the link describes.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the following lines in wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
# needed for wpa_gui to work 
ctrl_interface=DIR=<Dir on Gentoo: /var/run/wpa_supplicant> GROUP=<Group on gentoo: plugdev> 
# needed to allow wpa_gui to alter the configuration 
update_config=1
```

Comment: comment was to long going to edit my post, thanks